# Proof: $x_{1-n}$ linear dependant, w alternating multilinearform $\Rightarrow$ $w(x_1,...,x_n)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $X$ a $F$-linear Space with $dim_FX=n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $w$ be an alternating multilinearform on $X$ and let $x_1,\cdots ,x_n\in X$ be linear dependant. Show that $w(x_1,\cdots ,x_n)=0$.

Now from wikipedia: "if the same vector is 2 times inserted in a ml form then it becomes 0"

Can someone provide me good definitions to work here?

And isn't that the reason why the determinante works in the first place?

Comment: Note that the determinant is 'the' unique alternating multilinear form $D$ such that $D(I_n)=1$ (normalization). As a result any alternating multilinear form is simply a multiple of the determinant. So without loss of generality you can prove this for determinant.

Comment: well, that helps me in understanding it, but proof-wise i don't think even introducing the determinant will safe me any work, because then i have to proof that the determinant is 0 $\iff$ linear dependent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is linearly dependent there exists $a_1,\dots,a_n\in F$ not all $0$, such that $a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n=0$. Therefore if $a_i$ is the scalar different than $0$ we have $x_i=-\frac{a_1}{a_i}x_1-\dots-\frac{a_n}{a_i}x_n$. Evaluating $w$ and using the statement you found in wikipedia one has
$$w(x_1,\dots,x_n)=w(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n)=w(x_1,\dots,-\frac{a_1}{a_i}x_1-\dots-\frac{a_n}{a_i}x_n,\dots,x_n)=-\frac{a_1}{a_i}w(x_1,\dots,x_1,\dots,x_n)-\dots-\frac{a_n}{a_i}w(x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots,x_n)=-0-\dots-0=0$$

Comment: Hi, yeah that's the way i thought to depuzzle this, but i have a question: does the statement from wikipedia follows trivially of the properties from multilinear forms? Also a question: what you mean with "not all 0 such that" is the 0 a typo?

Comment: Hi! Maybe the "," I added makes it clear. The thing is that amongst $a_1,\dots,a_n$ there must be some $a_i$ different than $0$. This is guaranteed by the linear dependence. Otherwise we can not divide by one of the coefficients.

Comment: The property on wikipedia is trivial. Since $w$ is alternating then if $x_i=x_j $  we have by definition $w(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_n)=-w(x_1,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n)=-w(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_n)$. If we rename $y=w(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_n)$ we just proved $y=-y$. Then $y=0$. There is a catch however. The field $F$ must have characteristic different than 2.

Comment: i hope i dont sound stupid, but in the final line at the beginning, you "factored"(?) out all coefficients, what did you there? (if theres a term for that). What do you mean with "characteristics different than 2"?

Comment: Well, which fields have characteristic 2?

Comment: The characteristic of a field is the number of times you have to sum the multiplicative identity $1$ to get $0$. For example the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ of number module 2 has multiplicative identitity the class $\[1\]$ and $\[1\]+\[1\]=\[0\]$. You didn't sound stupid. I don't understand which line. If it is on the comment the latex format doesn't work well in the comments. The "if we rename" should be before the "$y=...$"

Comment: oh, i mean $w(x_1,\dots,x_n)=w(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n)=w(x_1,\dots,-\frac{a_1}{a_i}x_1-\dots-\frac{a_n}{a_i}x_n,\dots,x_n)=-\frac{a_1}{a_i}w(x_1,\dots,x_1,\dots,x_n)-\dots-\frac{a_n}{a_i}w(x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots,x_n)=-0-\dots-0=0$                  at the end you factored out $-a_1/a_i$, but i dont understand what you did there. To the characteristics problem: well then any infinite field is handled by your proof or? (since you cant add to get zero in those)

Comment: Yeap. Any infinite field will do. I used the multilinearity. In particular the linearity in the ith term. Maybe this notation will help:

Comment: $w(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n)=w(x_1,\dots,\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^n-\frac{a_1}{a_j}x_j,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^nw(x_1,\dots,-\frac{a_1}{a_j}x_j,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^n-\frac{a_1}{a_j}w(x_1,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_n)$

Comment: mmh, i don't grasp it, why can you pull the sum out of the brackets? don't you then have to also devide any other vector by it? or other asked: are there any rules for calculating with multilin. forms where i can understand this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41745/discussion-between-ivan-mauricio-burbano-and-saturatedexpo).